# How to map domain to hosting server

Tags: dns, web-hosting

My client have a dedicated server on liquedweb cloud service and we my web app is hosted on that server. We want our users to map their domain to our server. So they can enjoy our web app by using their domain name. What information I need to provide to my user so he can map domain and what information I need from them? 
I don't know much(in fact anything) about domain mapping

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if the server has a dedicated IP address or is natted.

If the server has a dedicated IP address you can ask your clients to point their entire domain to you server by adding the following A records:

```
Host     TTL      Protocol  Type     IP Address

@        300      IN        A        1.1.1.1
www      300      IN        A        1.1.1.1
```

Not all domain hosts ask for TTL,if not dont worry about it.

If you want just their subdomain to point to your server (subdomain.website.com)

```
subdomain         IN        A        0.0.0.1
```

TTL is optional in some systems, in this case the default will be used.

Generally it is recommended that you use an IP for the Apex record and not a domain name. EG: example.com is the apex, www.example.com is the www subdomain.

A typical configuration would be below:

```
Host      TTL     Protocol  Type     Result

@         300     IN        A        1.1.1.1
www       300     IN        CNAME    example.com
```

This is the same config as the top example but using CNAME example.com. It is the same as using A 1.1.1.1, it just means you only need to change one record.

If your server details are a hostname and not an IP address, most systems will not let you use the hostname for the apex so you will need to find out the IP address. (A simple method is to use the nslookup command or dig command).

TTL is how long in seconds a record last before it expires. If you are unsure what you are doing I recommend lowering this so you can correct mistakes more quickly.

Comment: My server has static IP and I configured domain using A record type. Now My domain is taking me to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi instead of my website.

Comment: I believe that is all that would need to be provided to your user

Comment: I have nothing to do on servers. It means I can map my domain to any web hosting if i know the IP?

Comment: If the server is correctly configured for that domain then yes, just the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Different methods for the different servers. For most of the servers, you have to change the nameservers of your domain.

This mostly needs when your domain registrar and hosting provider both are different.

First Login into your hosting account, navigate to the account details,
then copy the nameservers from there...which would be like :- dns1.hostingprovider.com
dns2.hostingprovider.com

After that, Go to control panel of your domain. Navigate to the nameservers

You will see the link:-  dns1.domainregistrar.com
                         dns2.domainregistrar.com

Paste the above links at the place of below links.

Answer (score 0):

They need the IP address (and possibly instructions on how to configure their DNS servers (which means a variety of different sets of instructions for different servers and control panels)).

You need the domain name.

Comment: and what about cname? whats this and do i need to put any value in it?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record). You don't have to touch it to achieve what you want.